# InvalidProtocolBufferException strange behaviour

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am getting InvalidProtocolBufferException while parsing at server side for the below message

```
attribute {

 name: "attr1"

  value {
    type: BOOL

    nrOfElements: 1

    inner_value {

      theBoolean: false

    }

  }

}
```

and when i send true in place of false, its going without error.

```
attribute {

  name: "attr1"

  value {

    type: BOOL 

    nrOfElements: 1

    inner_value {

      theBoolean: true

    }

  }

}
```

what could be causing the error? Error received is below:

com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.

error is thrown at where i called parseFrom() at server side. Please help me.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to fetch and parse the input. We don't have enough context at the moment.

Comment: Also which version of protocol huffers & stack trace could be useful

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Here is the code i am using.. and i am using protocol buf 2.4.1.
i am getting error at parseFrom().
                                                                     
DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream());
int size = inStream.readInt();
byte[] buff = new byte[size];
inStream.read(buff,0, size);
SocketRpcProtos.Request rpcRequest = SocketRpcProtos.Request.parseFrom(rawRpcBuffer);

Comment: With this approach, I am getting error: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved.. Here is the fix. At the client side:
I am sending size of the data first then data of that size. The value of size will be used at server side.
There is byte '0' in the string array at the end(for false i think). So the size i am sending is less than the data size. so it is giving error.

Comment: I am facing the exact same InvalidProtocolBufferException & message,  but on parsing the protocol object at the client end received over Http. Any suggestion!? I feel your answer is very obscure and restricted to your own case!